# Html change part of the label text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript code:

```
window.toggle = function() {
 if( document.getElementById("calendar").style.display=='none' ){
     document.getElementById("calendar").style.display = '';
     $(".icon-chevron-down").removeClass("icon-chevron-down").addClass("icon-chevron-up");
     document.getElementById("label").innerText = "Hide calendar";
 } else {
     document.getElementById("calendar").style.display = 'none';
     $(".icon-chevron-up").removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
     document.getElementById("label").innerText = "Show calendar";
 }
}
```

I would like to change only a part of label, because I wouldn't like to remove bootstrap icons. Like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/RkaQD/2/

Have you any hints how to cope with this disappering bootstrap icons?

Edit:

Maybe I write some example what I would like to have:

v 'show calendar'

^ 'hide calendar'

v 'show calendar'

^ 'hide calendar'

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you are changing the inner text of the element with ID label.... this label has the two icon elements inside it as well besides the text.

What i did was putting the text "Hide Calendar" and "Show Calendar" into a span with ID and then changing the inner text of the span ( not the label )
So instead of having:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
    Show calendar  
<i class="icon-calendar"></i>
```

You must have

```
<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
    <span id="display_text">Show calendar</span>  
<i class="icon-calendar"></i>
```

And change the 2 lines on your JavaScript from

```
document.getElementById("label").innerText = "Hide calendar";
document.getElementById("label").innerText = "Show calendar";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("display_text").innerText = "Hide calendar";
document.getElementById("display_text").innerText = "Show calendar";
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's innerHTML nstead of innerText.

Comment: For *text* it's either `textContent` (Mozilla, Webkit, Opera) or `innerText` (for IE); `innerHTML` is, as the name suggests, for setting the HTML.

Comment: Thanks guys, but what I wanted to do is to change 'show' to 'hide' text in "show calendar". And it does not seem to work?